# Interface usage in Java and PHP in case of GUI calling a module

Tags: java, php, spring, tdd, inversion-of-control

I have a module1 (GUI) and a module2 (Ordering).
From module1 I need to access the OrderingService found in module2.

I can of course create an OrderingService interface and an OrderingServiceImpl as a concrete implementation. This is a good practice in relation to Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP).

From my knowledge in Java I can benefit from module decoupling (I can change OrderingServiceImpl but module1 will not be affected and RECOMPILED) and I can use dependency injection in Spring to automatically use the right implementation. Regarding TDD I don't think you really need to create a OrderingServiceMockImpl because you can use a Mocking framework to mock the concrete class OrderingServiceImpl.

**When we only have a single concrete implementation is module decoupling the only real benefit?** I see in practice a lot of developers that always create an interface but don't really use more then one concrete implementation and I'm trying to figure out if there is something more to it or not.

I can't just accept the concept create interfaces "hoping" you will benefit from them later on. Isn't more **pragmatic** to change the code to an interface when you really have two different implementations?

Also I would also like to understand this from a PHP point of view, because code compilation is not an issue in dynamicly typed languages.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of using interfaces is to let you work on smaller pieces of your system independently, in terms of testing, of course, but also in terms of the amount of details you need to concentrate on to write the code and to understand it when you look at months later.  In some languages there are code management benefits too but this is not the primary motivation for using interfaces.

Comment: My curiosity is regarding the practice of some Java developers to create services like OrderService and OrderServiceImpl, every time for each Service.

Comment: This practice usually indicates applying a principle without THINKING about why!  Creating interfaces should be part of a thoughtful design process. Having only a single implementation of an interface is not bad if it contributes to testability, understandability and modularity.  A seminal paper is http://jmock.org/oopsla2004.pdf and a great book that covers this topic and much more is http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com

Answer (score 0):

Let's change your example a little bit, because I would never start with the UI. Assume I am building the OrderingService which need a repository for storing and retrieving orders.

I would always create an interface for that repository, even if it is totally unlikely that I will ever have two implementations for it. The reason for creating it, that I do not need or want real data access at this stage of the development. What I do is "programming by wishful thinking". I imagine there would be this magic contraption that makes it possible to store and retrieve my orders. I specify how I imagine this as an interface. In my tests I mock the interface and can build the OrderingService without even touching anything DB related yet.

I do the same with other dependencies that are adapters to the "outside world" (repositories, clients for calling other services, event publishers, etc).